# Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

Tags: java, android

Api key is correct , Check all things on console and **Places Api** & **Map Sdk for Android** is also enabled
but still it is not working. Saying : **Autocomplete widget closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED**
Please suggest if anyone have the better solution.

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

            if (!place.getAddress().toString().contains(place.getName())) {
                txtLocationAddress.setText(place.getName() + ", " + place.getAddress());
            } else {
                txtLocationAddress.setText(place.getAddress());
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + place.getLatLng());

            String str_latLng = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng());
            str_latLng = str_latLng.replace("lat/lng: ", "");
            str_latLng = str_latLng.replace("(", "");
            str_latLng = str_latLng.replace(")", "");
            String[] array_latLng = str_latLng.split(",");

            latitude = Double.valueOf(array_latLng[0]);
            longitude = Double.valueOf(array_latLng[1]);
            address = String.valueOf(place.getName() + " " + place.getAddress());
            txtLocationAddress.setText(address);
            showMarker(latitude, longitude, place.getLatLng());

        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(context, data);
            printToast("Error in retrieving place info");
            Log.e("resultCode", "" + resultCode);
            Log.e("status", "" + status);
        }
    }
}
```

Always getting result code 2 , google.json file also in my project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible -example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: **add your code**

Comment: added check this